# What does "Unzip the code tree and add the root directory of that code tree to your computer’s CLASSPATH environment variable." mean? (Java Mac OSx)

Tags: java

> Unzip the code tree and add the root directory of that code tree to
>   your computer’s CLASSPATH environment variable.

I am trying to teach myself Java with "Thinking in Java".  In order to run examples from source code the author provides I am prompted to download the code tree (which I have) and then to do with it what is stated above.  He gives this direction as if he has already told me what a CLASSPATH environment variable is.  There are directions for this on youtube for windows but not mac.  How can I take the source he gave me and make it runnable in eclipse?

My question has not been answered.  I don't even know what a CLASSPATH environment variable is so I can't possibly be asking specifically how to set mine.  I simply want to take the source the author gives me and import things from it/ open whatever files I want in eclipse.  I guess the best way to phrase this is please instruct me word for word how to meet the **intent** of what the author asked me to do on my Mac OSX machine.

Comment: Your title and your question differ slightly.  "How can I take the source he gave me and make it runnable in eclipse?" is not the same as "what does [...] mean?"  Which do you want to know??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How is the Java classpath set on a Mac?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5352584/how-is-the-java-classpath-set-on-a-mac)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to configure PATH and CLASSPATH for Java in Mac OS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23779254/how-to-configure-path-and-classpath-for-java-in-mac-os)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Unzip the code tree"

Run a program that will take the zip file you have downloaded and expand it to a directory (sub)tree, i.e., a set of files on your computer that are contained in a folder or directory, whichever you want to call it.

"... and add the root directory of that code tree to your computer’s CLASSPATH environment variable."

An environment variable is an item defined on your computer that is given a value, i.e. the set of environment variables is a set of name/value pairs. A CLASSPATH variable is significant to Java runtimes; it defines the directories and/or jar files that the Java runtime searches when it needs to load a class file.

So the instructions are telling you to unzip the zip file, to make it a set of files, and then to set or alter the CLASSPATH variable so that the root directory of the files you unzipped is defined in the CLASSPATH variable.

I don't know how to do that on a Mac; that you can get from one of these other links, no doubt.